# How to pass a list as an input of a function in Python

Tags: python, arrays, list, function

I am using Python, and I have a function which takes a list as the argument. For example, I am using the following syntax,

```
def square(x,result= []):
    for y in x:
        result.append=math.pow(y,2.0)
        return result

print(square([1,2,3]))
```

and the output is `[1]` only where I am supposed to get `[1,4,9]`.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: 1. Don't make mutable default arguments. 2. You can only `return` once.

Comment: Then how can I return an array as the output. Can you give me any idea? Thank you

Comment: Bring the return out of the for loop.

Comment: Try adjusting your indentation; it's important in Python...

Comment: You can use global list and modify accordingly in the function body. This needs not to return the list.

Comment: `map(lambda x: x**2, list_nums)`

Comment: @MaSH please don't recommend bad practices like that. There's no reason to use globals here.

Comment: Based on your comments it seems the answers here have resolved the issue. The SO culture [encourages you](http://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers) to mark the answer that has solved your problem as the accepted one. However, this isn't mandatory.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You are currently returning a value from your function in the first iteration of your `for` loop. Because of this, the second and third iteration of your `for` loop never take place. You need to move your `return` statement outside of the loop as follows:

```
import math

def square(x):
    result = []
    for y in x:
        result.append(math.pow(y,2.0))
    return result 

print(square([1,2,3]))
```

**Output**

```
[1.0, 4.0, 9.0]
```

Comment: As someone used to brace based programming rather than indentation based, I must say that single tab changing where the function returns from is something I find horribly unintuitive.

Comment: But you still indent your code even if your using braces, don't you?

Answer (score 21):

Why not side-step the problem altogether?

```
def square(vals):
    return [v*v for v in vals]
```

---

**Edit:** The first problem, as several people have pointed out, is that you are short-circuiting your `for` loop. Your `return` should come *after* the loop, not in it.

The next problem is your use of `list.append` - you need to call it, not assign to it, ie `result.append(y*y)`. `result.append = y*y` instead overwrites the method with a numeric value, probably throwing an error the next time you try to call it.

Once you fix that, you will find another less obvious error occurs if you call your function repeatedly:

```
print(square([1,2,3])     # => [1, 4, 9]
print(square([1,2,3])     # => [1, 4, 9, 1, 4, 9]
```

Because you pass a mutable item (a list) as a default, all further use of that default item points back to *the same original list*.

Instead, try

```
def square(vals, result=None):
    if result is None:
        result = []
    result.extend(v*v for v in vals)
    return result
```

Comment: This doesn't really tell the OP where they are going wrong and is just a one liner of how to square an array

Comment: @ShaneQful: please take another look.

Comment: Apologies, my initial comment above was based on your initial succinct answer. Have an up vote :)

Comment: this is the only answer that even mentions the mistaken assignment to result.append, which is an error in all situations.

Answer (score 6):

We even use `result`?  You can use a list comprehension to generate your result which you then return.  I'm not sure why you passed `result` as a variable into the function, since it is not used.

Also, having `return result` inside your loop means the function returns the value on the first iteration, so it just returns the square of the first number in the list.

```
import math

def square(x):
    return [math.pow(y, 2) for y in x]

>>> print(square([1,2,3]))
[1.0, 4.0, 9.0]
```

Comment: Well, it could be seen as the initial value, for example. Perhaps OP intended `square([1,2,3],[100,200,300])` to return `[100,200,300,1,4,9]`.

Answer (score 3):

You should return outside the for loop. Otherwise, it will stop after first iteration.

```
def square(x):
    result=[]
    for y in x:
        result.append(math.pow(y,2.0)) # add to list after calculation
    return result 

print(square([1,2,3])
```

Comment: Append is a function you don't want to overwrite here.

Answer (score 3):

You might be interested in using [`yield`](https://stackoverflow.com/q/231767/321973)

```
def square(x):
    for y in x:
        yield math.pow(y, 2.0)
```

that way you can either call

```
for sq in square(x):
    ...
```

which won't generate the entire list of squares at once but rather one element per iteration, or use `list(square(x))` to obtain the full list on demand.

Answer (score 3):

This is a fun opportunity to use a slightly more functional style:

```
import math
map(lambda x:(math.pow(x,2)), [1,2,3])
```

This uses the `map` function, which takes a list and a function, and returns a new list where that function has been applied individually to each member of the list.  In this case, it applies the `math.pow(x,2)` function to each member of the list, where each number is x.

Notice that `map(lambda x:(math.pow(x,2)), [1,2,3])` returns an iterable, which is really convenient, but if you need to get a list back just wrap the entire statement in `list()`.

Answer (score 0):

your code doesn't make sense anywhere. syntax error at the end missing the closing bracket for the print, return call inside the for loop meaning it only executes once, and result.append is a function not a constructor sp the correct call is

```
result.append(math.pow(y,2))
```

the only thing that is not an issue is the passing of the list which is your question, the function is receiving the whole list if you do

```
def f(a):
    print a
f([1,2,3])
```

out

```
[1,2,3,]
```